# Why would an internal loop modify a coroutine?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Can somebody explain to me what is the difference between these coroutines?  Since I have to call the function each time either way, don't they, in effect, do the same thing?

```
IEnumerator MyRoutine()
{
    
        yield return null;
        Debug.Log("Hello");
}

IEnumerator MyRoutine2()
{
    while (true)
    {
        yield return null;
        Debug.Log("Hello");
    }
}
```

Why does the first one runs only once and the second forever?

Comment: Because it has a `while(true)` loop? I don't understand the confusion

Comment: Maybe the while statement is relevant.

Answer (score 3):

Coroutines are important when they are invoked multiple times. On first invocation, they execution will start from `{` part. And it will run till the keyword(s) `yield return` get(s) executed. Now, when the same coroutine is invoked again, code will continue from last `yield return` executed - next line / statement will be invoked.

---

Looking at your first example (statement), on first invocation the Coroutine will return `null`. On 2nd invocation, it will hit `Debug.Log("Hello")` and ends at `}`.

Compared to 2nd example (statement), where you have the `while(true) { }` loop. For first run those parts get executed:

```cs
{
    while (true)
    {
        yield return null; // ends here
```

This is pretty much the same as before. But on 2nd execution the behavior will change. It will run `Debug.Log("Hello")` again, but then it reaches end of `while(true) { }` loop, it checks for its condition (it is `true`) and goes again back to statement `yield return null` where it ends.

Comment: thank you so much my confusion was from the fact that I thought that when you encountered yield you re-run the entire function that is why I put the Debug.log(....) after yield return null;

Answer (score 0):

> Why does the first one runs only once and the second forever?

Because the first one exits after a single `yield return` and the second runs `yield return` in an infinite loop.

In this construction MyRoutine returns an IEnumerator, but its code doesn't actually run until someone enumerates the IEnumerator.

```
IEnumerator enum = MyRoutine();  //no code in MyRoutine runs yet
if (enum.MoveNext()) //this actually runs MyRoutine up through the first `yield return`
{
  var value = enum.Current;     
}
//the next call to enum.MoveNext() continues running MyRoutine _after_ the first `yield return`
var hasRows = enum.MoveNext(); //returns false as Debug.Log("Hello") runs and then MyRoutine exits
```

Comment: In Unity the `MoveNext` calls come from the framework itself (basically every frame) (see [Coroutines](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html)) ;)